# Nativescript Angular Cannot assign image to property after taking picture

Tags: angular, android-camera, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using nativescript-camera to capture image in my android apps but i always getting **TypeError: Cannot set property 'imageSource' of undefined**. I'm following the guide [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-camera/blob/master/demo-angular/app/app.component.ts) , all my camera code seems correct and i not sure where i did wrong.

```
export class SocialRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

    imageSource: ImageSource;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    capturePicture() {

        const options = {
        saveToGallery: false,
        allowsEditing: false,
        format: 'png'
        };

        camera.requestPermissions().then(
            function success() {
                camera.takePicture(options)
                .then((capturedImageAsset) => {

                    let imageSource = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource;

                    imageSource.fromAsset(capturedImageAsset)
                    .then((capturedImageSource: ImageSource) => {

                        console.log(capturedImageSource); // Display correctly
                        this.imageSource = capturedImageSource; // Error here, this.imageSource undefined
                    });
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log('Error -> ' + err.message);
                });
            }, 
            function failure() {
                // failed
            }
        );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context (`this`) will not be pointing to Angular component inside success function. You have to use arrow function or retain context in local variable.

```
success() => {
  // Using arrow function retains the context
  .... 
}
```